# How to save and load progress in scip for zimpl optimization?

Tags: scip, zimpl

I have been running optimization problems written in ZIMPL in scip.
However it takes too much time to finish.

I can hit Ctrl + C to stop it from running, and later run `optimize` again to resume it.
But if I accidentally hit Ctrl + C twice, or the `scip` process got killed, hours of progress would be gone.

Is there any way to save its progress?
(I checked `help`, but there is only *save/load parameter settings* in `set` sub menu, not what I am looking for.)